# How to add conditional pattern matching rules with IP restriction to Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I would like to configure a rule such that anything with a pending `+` will be redirect to a 404 page except for a certain `allow IP`.

eg.

If IP is 111.111.111.111, http://domain.com/12345+ will be processed (via php block)

Any other condition will return 404 not found

This rule should take precedence before the php block.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ "^/([0-9a-zA-Z]{5})\+$" {
    allow 111.111.111.111;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm-www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;               
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The above solution works for me, even though it shows a 403 forbidden instead of giving me 404 not found if coming from an unauthorized IP.

I would appreciate if someone can show me how to display an internal 404 page or even redirect to an external URL when 404 occurs.